# How to download a csv file in python from a server?

Tags: python, django, csv

```
from pip._vendor import requests

import csv

url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/abcd'

dataReader = csv.reader(open(url), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

exampleData = list(dataReader)

exampleData
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `import urllib.request` and then simply call `data_stream = urllib.request.urlopen(url)` to get a buffer of the file. You can then save the csv data as `data = str(data_stream.read()`, which may be a bit unclean depending on your source or encoded, so you may need to do some manipulation, but if not then you can just throw it into `csv.reader(data, delimiter=',')`

An example requiring translating from byte format that may work for you:

```
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data_csv = str(data.read())
# split out b' flag from string, then also split at newlines up to the last one
dataReader = csv.reader(data_csv.split("b\'",1)[1].split("\\n")[:-1], delimiter=",")
headers = reader.__next__()
exampleData = list(dataReader)
```

Comment: No problem glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Use [Python Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/).

```
import requests
r = requests.get(url)
lines = r.text.splitlines()
```

We use splitlines to turn the text into an iterable like a file handle. You should probably wrap it up in a try, catch block in case of errors.

Comment: cannot import requests

Comment: It's a library, you need to install it. Do a search online for python pip it's the package manager for python. If you couldn't be bothered run...

> pip install requests

Answer (score 1):

You need to use something like urllib2 to retrieve the file.
for example:

```
import urllib2
import csv
csvfile = urllib2.urlopen('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/abcd')
dataReader = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
do_stuff(dataReader)
```

Comment: cannot import urllib2

Comment: It is a lib that you download.